# User Data and Paid Customers When Converting WP SL App to Universal

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-8, win-universal-app

I have some existing Windows Phone Silverlight applications. I am considering porting some of them to universal apps. I can find a lot of information about the development side of things with regards to the port, but nothing that talks about the deployment issues.

For example, my existing WPSL app is a paid app with free trial and some customers have purchased. Do I need to do anything to ensure those paid customers continued to receive the non-trial features if I push a universal app package? The purchase API's are different, are the backend servers/purchase records compatible, or is there no way to keep paid customers at the paid version?

Also, what about app settings from isolationstorage settings and data files saved to local storage by the app? Will these be kept and accessible through the new API's when the new package is downloaded as an update, or will the fact the package is a different framework/version/appid cause the data to be deleted? Do I need to give the package the same id's as the Silverlight version to ensure all this stuff just works?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should just work without needing to do anything fancy.

It will be the same app, just a different implementation. Your paid users will stay paid and your upgrading users will keep their data.

If you associate and add the new appx to the same app entry on the dashboard then everything should work smoothly. When you associate the runtime app the product ID, etc. will be set to match the existing version in the store (via a mapping since the actual values are different)

IsolatedStorage maps to ApplicationData.LocalFolder and LocalSettings (this was already true on Windows Phone 8 - you could use either API)

See [What's next for Windows Phone 8 developers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn655121(v=vs.105).aspx) for an overview of your options.

See [Migrating your Windows Phone 8 app to a Windows Runtime XAML app](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/dn642486(v=vs.105).aspx) for information on feature changes you'll need to be aware of.

Comment: Thanks Rob,that's great. Appreciate the link too.